# Chrome does't recognize pdf files

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, pdf

I have installed Xubuntu 18.04 LTS , but I have an issue with pdf files,
I have WPS office installed, so all pdf files (even downloaded files) have the type : application/wps-office.pdf, and they are not recognized by google chrome. here attached screenshots :

[image: Shows type as Microsoft Word in Thunar]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "not recognized by Chrome"?